# Realtek 8188 WiFi module continuous transmit mode

Tags: wifi, emc, software, certification

I'm going to certify an appliance with a RT8188 WiFi module, for which I did the Android port and wrote the software. The certification laboratory is now asking me to write a test software that can put the module in Continuous Transmit mode to test every channel, data rate and output power for compliance within the European standards. Nor the module distributor or the appliance engineers can help me with documentation or example source code to fulfill this task. Digging in the Linux driver I've found few hits, bot nothing useful.

Any hints? Thank you in advance.

Comment: First hint would be to get the datasheet and any other relevant documents from Realtek and read them. If there's something in them you don't understand, that might be something you can ask here, unless Realtek won't let you link the docs here. If they are behind NDAs, you're probably stuck with the support Realtek provide.

Comment: Isn't the WiFi module certified? I don't think you need to certify the WiFi part unless you changed the design somehow.

Comment: @ammar.cma the module is FCC certified, and apparently EU regulations cannot inherit that certification.

Comment: The module distributor, if you mean an actual business in the EU and not a fly by night reseller or ebay shop, should provide the certification of the module, not you,  imho.